# How to double sum or triple sum up over the list of functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, function-construction, special-functions

I'm dealing with a summation problem by now using a list of function $F(x; \theta_i)$. The function is defined as
\begin{align*}
  F(x; \theta) = 1 - \Phi[\Phi^{-1}(1 - \frac{x}{2}) - \theta] + \Phi[-\Phi^{-1}(1 - \frac{x}{2}) - \theta]
\end{align*}
I have a list of the parameter $\Theta = \{ \theta_1, \theta_2, .... , \theta_K \}$, and now I would like to calculate the following summation:
\begin{align*}
  I(\Theta) = \sum_{i, j, k} \int F(x; \theta_i) F(0.05 + 0.95x; \theta_j) d F(x; \theta_k)
\end{align*}

so, there are $K(K-1)(K-2)$ terms in total for the summation. I know how to double sum for simple functions like $\frac{1}{x^3 + y^3}$ over the range of $x, y = 1, ..., 100$. But now we have is a list of parameter values and a given function. Then how to construct the triple summation over script $i, j, k$?

What I can provide now is the code for function F, and a list for $\Theta$:

```
F[x_, \[Theta]_] := 1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1],InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1],  1 - x/2] - \[Theta]] + CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], -InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1],  1 - x/2] - \[Theta]]
f[x_, \[Theta]_] := Exp[-\[Theta]^2/2]*Cosh[\[Theta] * InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - x/2]] 
Theta = Range[0, 1, 0.02]
```

Then I don't know what's the next step. All my trying seems to be failure now.

Comment: You can provide a list of values to the ``Sum``, for example ``θ = Range[0, 1, 0.02]; Sum[F[x, θi] F[x, θj] dF[θk], {θi, θ}, {θj, θ}, {θk, θ}]``

Comment: Ok, let me have a try!

Comment: But your solution raise a problem of unwanted term as $\theta_i = \theta_j = \theta_k$

Comment: A simple way to omit them: ``Sum[If[θi != θj != θk, F[x, θi] F[x, θj] dF[θk], 0], {θi, θ}, {θj, θ}, {θk, θ}]``